# Java - Parse double from file containing double and int

Tags: java, parsing, vector

I have the following method in java which reads a file of numbers (tab separated) and puts the numbers in a vector of Doubles

```java
public static Vector<Double> getData(String path,int dataNum) throws Exception
{
    File file = new File(path);
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);
    scan.useDelimiter("\t");

    Vector<Double> content = new Vector<Double>();
    int limit = 0;

    while(scan.hasNext() && limit < dataNum)
    {
        content.add(Double.parseDouble(scan.next()));
        limit++;
    }

    return content;
}
```

This is my sample file

```
0   20000   -9.2149 1.6078  4.1023  0.0089185   0.0057066   0.015156
```

However, when i run the code, I get the following error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "0
0"
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1222)
    at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:510)
    at midterm.main.getData(main.java:91)
    at midterm.main.main(main.java:123)
```

I believe my mistake is that I am parsing double but my file contains 0 and 2000 and that java sees them as integer. But EVEN if they are integers, i want them to be treated as Doubles and still go into my vector.

Comment: point of generics: use `Vector<Double> content = new Vector<Double>();`. That's not an answer, but is something you should be doing if you're using generics.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did make the change you said... However, it still gives me the same error

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue if a tab separates each number.

Comment: Same here. Cannot reproduce your error. Also, to @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans in Java SE 8 you can just do `Vector<Double> content = new Vector<>();`

Comment: This is not the entire content of my file. It's a file of 165 MB. MANY lines. but each line, the numbers are tab separated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This is not the entire content of my file. It's a file of 165 MB. MANY lines. but each line, the numbers are tab separated.

The problem is with the delimiter then: you need to allow `\n` to be a delimiter as well:

```
scan.useDelimiter("[\t\n]");
```

Otherwise, the last number of the first line and the first number from the second line would be bunched together into a single string that looks like this: `"0\n0"` and prints like two zeros on different lines, matching the error message that you get.

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/MiyMJ3)

Comment: +1 for explaining what is (very likely) going on.  I would consider the other answer (read line-by-line, split and parse) a cleaner approach, though.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a scanner, just read the entire line in, split it on "\t" and then run through the resulting String[] with a "for-each" style for loop?

```
import java.util.*;
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "0\t20000\t-9.2149\t1.6078\t4.1023\t0.0089185\t0.0057066\t0.015156";
    String[] columns = input.split("\t");
    Vector<Double> dv = new Vector<Double>();
    for(String s: columns) {
      dv.add(Double.parseDouble(s));
    }
    System.out.println(dv.toString());
  }
}
```

Output:

```
[0.0, 20000.0, -9.2149, 1.6078, 4.1023, 0.0089185, 0.0057066, 0.015156]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I think I was a bit unclear. that is a SAMPLE file that I've shared. The actual file is 165MB and has thousands of lines. BUT each line's numbers are tab separated

Comment: yes, obviously, and that's why you test with a single line hardcoded. Does that work? great! find out what line things go wrong on because then the error is not with your code, but with your data.